# How do I scp a filename with spaces?

Tags: command-line, ssh, transfer, scp

I'm having a little difficulty using `scp` to transfer files from a remote computer. The issue apparently has to do with the name of the directory the files are contained in. They're on a CD drive called `photos 4` (with a space between `photos` and `4`). When I attempted the transfer, I used the following command:

```
scp [remote username]@192.168.1.X:/media/[remote username]/photos\ 4/file.jpg /home/[username]/Pictures
```

However, I get an error message in return saying `No directory: /media/[remote username]/photos`. I thought the backslash would escape the space so that the directory would be read as `photos 4`.

Can someone fill me in on what I'm doing wrong here?

(As an aside, I made a copy of `file.jpg` to the remote computer's desktop and then ran the command:

```
scp [remote username]@192.168.1.X:/home/[remote username]/Desktop/file.jpg /home/[username]/Pictures
```

and it worked, so that escape sequence seems to be the culprit. I just can't figure out what's wrong with it.)

Comment: Main lesson here: quit using spaces in file names. Even Apple corporation agrees on this now:  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202808

Comment: That's fine, unless you're scp'ing files that you didn't name.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Spaces in directories or filenames are the natural enemy of a Linux system but can of course be *escaped* with due diligence. There are 3 possibilities that you could try:

1. `scp [remote username]@192.168.1.X:"'/media/remote_username/photos 4/file.jpg'" .`
2. `scp [remote username]@192.168.1.X:"/media/remote_username/photos\ 4/file.jpg" .`
3. `scp [remote username]@192.168.1.X:/media/remote_username/photos\\\ 4/file.jpg .`

All should work but some are syntactically easier to understand than others...

**References:**

- [How to escape spaces in path during scp copy in linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19858176/how-to-escape-spaces-in-path-during-scp-copy-in-linux)

Comment: How about `scp` multiple files with the same extension? I have tried `"{file1,file2}".pdf` and `{"file1,file2"}.pdf` but it doesn't work: `No such file or directory`. However, your first option for one file does work. But, for more than one file, how do you do that? Please help!

Comment: @Pathros This looks like it could be a new question? I suspect what is happening is that the quoting has prevented the bash filename expansion you are after...

Comment: @Pathros Not tested, but to do multiple files I would assume you can do {"file1","file2"}

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix for ZSH users,

1. scp 'username@192.168.1.X:/media/"photos 4"/file.jpg' /home/username/Pictures
2. scp 'username@192.168.1.X:/media/"photos 4"/"file with space.jpg"' /home/username/Pictures

Comment: How about `scp` multiple files with the same extension? I have tried `"{file1,file2}".pdf` and `{"file1,file2"}.pdf` but it doesn't work: `No such file or directory`. However, your first option for one file does work. But, for more than one file, how do you do that? Please help!